# Div full height - Not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use the following code to display a div (with background color) with full height.

HTML

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="span5 fill">
        <div class="test">
           here is a lot of text....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html,body {
height:100%;

}

.container {
    height:100%;
}

.fill{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#990000;
    color:#efefef;
}
```

Actually it works but it's not responsive despite percentage heigh properties.

How can I fix this problem? The background should always have the same height as the content - full height...

[Here you can see a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe3zS.png)

Comment: Do you have a .test in your css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main element needs to have the background color.

Try adding:

```
.test {
 background-color: #990000;
 margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I also use sometimes is:

```
height:100vh;
```

The **vh** unit stands for "Viewport height" (there's also vw for Width), and it basically uses your viewport (most of the time your browser window) height size, so this might fit your needs perfectly.

Here you can check the browser support for "vh": http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 0):

This below  link is a demo which increases the height of the text div as your content height increases

```
.fill{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#990000;
    color:#efefef;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/maxspan/328vxn54/